# Azure VM: too frequent DNS lookup [TTL 60]

Tags: azure, dns, centos, azure-virtual-machine, ttl

I have a VM setup on Azure (classic VM running CentOS).  I am developing my mobile app that connect with RESTful API's hosted on Azure VM.  My mobile app performance was slow and on investigation, I found DNS lookup to the FQDN of my Azure VM is too long (about 5-5.5 seconds per lookup) and very frequent.  Attached is the output of "dig" tool on my Mac.

[Dig tool output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtxRi.jpg)

Is there a way I can control TTL for the Azure VM's?  Would it help if I buy a static IP and map it to my Azure VM's FQDN?  Also, is there a way to reduce the DNS lookup time?

Thanks,
Giri

Answer (score 0):

The TTL is associated to the domain name. If you want to increase the TTL you would need to purchase a domain name and associate it with the domain. With your own domain name you can set whatever TTL you require.

You would be far better developing against a domain name as this will give you the most flexibility with regards to developing against it, since you are able to move the location that your application points to, and should your app be particularly successful you would need a domain name for load balancing etc.

Comment: Thanks Michael!  This helped.  I added a CNAME configuration to my sub domain and mapped it to Azure FQDN.  This way I could control my TTL.  My network calls look lot better now as DNS lookup is now not that frequent as it used to be.  Appreciate your inputs.